# Windows 8 DNS issue

Tags: networking, windows-8, dns

I've been having this weird problem for a couple of months now.

twitter.com works perfeclty at work but not at home. I tried Google OpenDns but it didn't help. I tried disabling the DNS client service and it didn't work. I keep flushing the DNS cache but that doesn't work either. I also have ubuntu installed on my computer and twitter.com works just fine from home on Ubuntu.

Twitter.com is just one domain, I've been having this problem with multiple other domains

When I run nslookup I get the following:

```
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    twitter.com
Addresses:  199.16.156.230
          199.16.156.70
          199.16.156.6
```

When I try tracert. I get the following:

```
Tracing route to twitter.com [199.16.156.102]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3    76 ms    53 ms    68 ms  172.31.32.14
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6   157 ms   143 ms   123 ms  46.42.84.234
  7   158 ms   148 ms   159 ms  84-235-94-105.saudi.net.sa [84.235.94.105]
  8   190 ms   162 ms   123 ms  84-235-120-22.igw.com.sa [84.235.120.22]
  9   239 ms   248 ms     *     84-235-95-230.saudi.net.sa [84.235.95.230]
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11   277 ms   238 ms   254 ms  xe-3-0-1.iad1-cr1.twttr.com [199.16.159.127]
 12   249 ms   293 ms   273 ms  ae50.atl1-er1.twttr.com [199.16.159.73]
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14   283 ms   268 ms   248 ms  199.16.156.102

Trace complete.
```

When I tried IE's diagnostics I got the following error message:

```
resource (twitter.com) is online but isn't responding to connection attempts. Detected 
The remote computer isn’t responding to connections on port 443, possibly due to firewall or security policy settings, or because it might be temporarily unavailable. Windows couldn’t find any problems with the firewall on your computer.
```

P.S. I upgraded from Windows 7 and I never had that problem on Windows 7

Comment: Post the contents of your hosts file.  What security software do you have installed?

Comment: I don't have any Firewall software (Except for Windows Firewall of course)
No Antivirus either.
The hosts file was is empty (no entries)

Comment: It being empty is odd because it should have at least one to define 'localhost' you sure about that and 'Windows Defender' should also be installed.  Are you changing your Router's DNS or the local computer's?

Comment: # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself. Other entries including the localhost at commented out

Comment: That might be true but by default it should exist in the hosts file did you remove that entry before the upgrade address my other concern and/or question

Comment: No, both entries (ipv4 & ipv6) are there but commented
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost

Comment: Windows defender is installed and I don't have access to the Router's DNS. I said earlier that I tried Google OpenDNS but it didn't work so I switched back to local DNS

Comment: So it's not empty... Anyways I suspect the problem is the router.  I assume what websites work and what websites don't work is random

Comment: here are the contents of the hosts file http://pastebin.com/88H4GLSX

Comment: Actually websites that don't work are always the same sites. And the reason I didn't suspect the router is because the other OS (Ubuntu) works perfectly fine

Comment: Try booting with safe mode with networking support.  This will eliminate any program that might be working I the background

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10942/discussion-between-ramhound-and-computerjy)

Comment: It took a long time to figure out how to start Safe mode in Windows 8 but I figured it out and tried and twitter.com still doesn't work. The same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a [small discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10942/discussion-between-ramhound-and-computerjy) the author tried [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) instead which apparently worked.  I highly suspect  that just the processing of changing the DNS ( again ) resolved the issue.  There is no technical reason OpenDNS shouldn't have worked.

> OpenDNS:
>   208.67.222.222 
>   208.67.222.220